# MVC .net add/edit css class for helper.TextBox extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a MVC extension to auto apply attributes to html inputs. Which is all working as expected however if i want to add a css class to the html input and it already has a css class the code bombs as the attribute is already set.

Heres my code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString LockableTextBox(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, object value, object htmlAttributes, bool locked)    
    {
        RouteValueDictionary dic = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        if (locked)
        {
            dic.Add("readonly", "readonly");
            dic.Add("class", "field-locked");
        }
        return helper.TextBox(name, value, dic);
    }
```

I call it like so:

```
@Html.LockableTextBox("Initals", Model.Initals, new {}, Model.Locked)
```

which works, but this call does not

```
@Html.LockableTextBox("Initals", Model.Initals, new {@Class="field"}, Model.Locked)
```

How do i change the dic.Add("class", "field-locked") line so that it adds a my extra class to the existing class attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like simple `Dictionary`. Check if you have already such key and append your string to existing value, otherwise add new.

```
public static MvcHtmlString LockableTextBox(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, object value, object htmlAttributes, bool locked)    
    {
        RouteValueDictionary dic = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        if (locked)
        {
            dic.Add("readonly", "readonly");
            if (dic.ContainsKey("class"))
               dic["class"] += " field-locked";
            else 
               dic.Add("class", "field-locked");
        }
        return helper.TextBox(name, value, dic);
    }
```